# css selector (adjust_imagemode:hover ~ [title="gradiant"]) does nothing

Tags: html, css, hover, selector

I want a div with the title "gradiant" to reduce its opacity when an adjacent div with class "adjust_imagemode" has a hover state. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="slides_gradiant_bottom_heavy" title="gradiant"></div>
<div class="adjust_imagemode"> - </div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.adjust_imagemode:hover + [title="gradiant"] {
    opacity: .01;
}
```

I tried with and without quotation marks around the title. No luck. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sibling selectors select siblings that are present **after** the reference element in the DOM and **not before**. You need to change the order of elements if you want to use CSS selectors.

Comment: There's no previous sibling selector in CSS

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks, and that fixed it!